# WPF + MVVM: Override autocomplete in DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, autocomplete

I've been searching for quite a while, but cannot figure out how to override the autocomplete functionality in a DataGridComboBoxColumn.

What I want to do is what is explained here, except for a combobox: [Searching for items in a list box](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/searching-for-items-in-a-listbox/)

That is: *I want to be able to enter any string and then apply a filter to the ComboBox items in the DataGridComboBoxColumn to show only those items that match this as a substring*.

I'm new to WPF and have been searching online for a while. I've found things like EventSetters and CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors, but I can't get a clear picture of the possibilities (and impossibilities).

I've got:

```
  <DataGrid ... >
    ...
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      ...
      <MyCustomDataGridComboBoxColumn Header="My Header" MinWidth="200" >
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.MyData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding DataItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="HardwareId" />
          </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.MyFilteredData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
            <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding DataItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="HardwareId" />
            <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding DataContext.MyNewDataItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
          </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      </MyCustomDataGridComboBoxColumn>
      ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Ideally, I'd like to create a new class that inherits from DataGridComboBoxColumn and supply it with some custom logic, such as supplying an anonymous function in its constructor so that the autocomplete behavior can be overridden in different ways in the future.

Is this even possible, or am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying your approach is wrong, however, I would approach it differently. For me it seems easier to use a DataGridTemplateColumn and supply a ComboBox that has the functionality you speak of.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnName" Width="*">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <YourCustomComboBox/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Edit:

A while ago I needed a ComboBox with the same functionality. I ended up combining a TextBox with a Popup control because it gave me much more control over it.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="editBox"/>
<Popup x:Name="textboxPopup" Width="{Binding ElementName=editBox, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                     PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=editBox}"
                     StaysOpen="False"
                     IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsOpen, Mode=OneWay}">
  <Grid>
    <DockPanel MaxHeight="500">
      <ListView SelectionMode="Single"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Suggestions}"
              Name="popupList">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"Color="LightBlue"/>
              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
          </Style.Resources>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
  </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the codebehind I subscribed to the TextChanged event and a few other events that came in handy. I can't share all my code because it is production code. However there are a few other people on the internet with similar implementations: [using a ComboBox](http://manoranjanmsnet.blogspot.nl/2011/07/auto-complete-combobox-in-wpf.html), [using a textbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox) and of course the link you posted in your question. There is more than enough out there.

And about using your custom control as a TargetType... I don't see anything wrong with that, I do it all the time.

The error with the CellTemplate shouldn't occur. Are you using it correctly? [See this link for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your response. I've abstracted away from the DataGridComboBoxColumn, which is a custom class already. I'm not going to change this right now. However, could I do <Style TargetType="MyCustomComboBox"> as well? Furthermore, it's not just the grid I'm having trouble with: How would I put autocomplete functionality in a ComboBox? Can I attach a handler to an event? If so, which event? A code snippet would be much appreciated.

Comment: Edit: Note that when using your suggestion, I get the error "The member "CellTemplate" is not recognized or is not accessible."

Comment: Hi @Diana, I expanded my answer to address your comments.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for the update. However, this has unfortunately not brought me closer to a solution. I've been searching the net for things like Triggers, Behaviors and the like, but I do not find examples without codebehind (which goes against MVVM)